# Enable HomeGroup in WIndows 2012

Tags: windows, networking

In the following path in my Windows 2012 Standard install I see HomeGroup, just like in Windows 8.
Control Panel/System and Security/Action Centre -> Maintaince -> HomeGroup.

It says: "You cant access or create a HomeGroup right now".  And pressing the view settings button seems to do nothing.

Should this work?  Seems silly to have it there if it does not work?  Or do I need to enable something else before it will work?

thanks